# Creating Hierarchical data with a single Column in Talend

Tags: java, talend, data-integration

I have a dataset that Looks like : [Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzrYF.png)

In talend, and I have to create Hierarchical data using these columns, sample output is:

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyeyT.png)

I can do it using TJavaRow but I cannot code, I have to do it purely using Talend components.

So far I've tried Using THashOutput (Storing the data in the memory) and then Left joining the dataset with the one stored in the Memory using the Main.ID = Prev.ID -1 
But i have received the data in the following format:

```
Asset | Null | Null
Currency and deposit | Asset | Null
Currency | Currency and deposit | Asset
```

.. and so on.

Any sort of help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Try the solution here: [Parent-Child relationship in Talend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49927959/parent-child-relationship-in-talend?rq=1)

Comment: Take a look at HSQLDb that is in Talend and can be used to do recursive SQL queries. It's just as out of the box as your Java solution but uses built in components.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Dataset and ouput you mentioned, output is dependent on the `codes`.

`codes` has length 10, that means output could have depth 10, dependent on previous `codes`.
I suggest you write a little algorithm (code) instead of using Talend as it'll be difficult implementing this using purely Talend components.